# Jquery/Js : Select and navigate to link embeded in a flash element

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, element, selector

I would like make a script for Greasemonkey (GM),that find and navigate in a link embed in a flash element.

I think that is possible to make it to work with function .click() ,but won't work :(

Here's the source code of the page that contains flash elements..
[Source code](http://pastebin.com/nk0dLLbF)

Is possible to make that to work?

Thanks in advance.

LUCA.

Answer (score 0):

Flash runs inside of a plugin within the browser, so from an external code point of view it's a black box. The only way to be able to programatically access a link embedded within a Flash element is to have the Flash object pass the link to your script via loadvars.

Comment: loadvars? Can you elaborate on that? I don't understand how that would work (which doesn't mean it won't :)